# How to check SRAM usage for cortex m3 for an application

Tags: arm, cortex-m, iar, memory-size

For Cortex-M3, how to check maximum SRAM usage by an embedded application running on it. Should we check linker map file and stack usage generated by IAR or should we try with writing a function which check current SRAM and call it in application at various place at runtime. Which method should be used.

Comment: there is no one answer that will work.  first off you should know what your usage is by analysis.  but a valgrind type approach is pretty common. fill memory with a pattern, being embedded say in the bootstrap, then at some point examine the memory and see how much has been changed/overwritten...If you have not covered all the possible execution paths and consumption use cases, then the results are not all that valid though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily, because stack usage differs by quite a lot, and can not be known at compile time, unless you have some restrictions (no proper recursion for example).

That said, there are some tools that might help you get worst-case stack usage:

- StackAnalyser (https://www.absint.com/stackanalyzer/index.htm)
- GNATstack (https://www.adacore.com/gnatpro/toolsuite/gnatstack)

(There's also some development on this topic in Rust: https://blog.japaric.io/stack-analysis/)